# ScheduledExecutorService Stops Running Randomly

Tags: java, runnable, scheduledexecutorservice, discord-jda

I have a pretty complicated bot using Discord JDA API, and for my periodic checker to check status changes, I have a `ScheduledExecutorService`. The problem is that when I input commands to the bot, there's a random(?) chance of the service to just stop working, making the whole program unresponsive without any error in stacktrace. I deduced this by putting a simple timer counter, and it just seems to stop randomly (not really, more like it doesn't have a definite pattern to it). This is the class of the checker:

```
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Guild;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.User;
import us.verif.bot.sql.Sql;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class PeriodicCheck implements Runnable {
    int i = 0;
    private JDA jda;

    public PeriodicCheck(JDA jda) {
        this.jda = jda;
    }


    public void run() {
        i++;
        System.out.println(i);
        try {
            Connection connection = DataSource.getConnection();
            connection.setCatalog("verifus");
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("select * from `activatedservers` where `expireDate` <= NOW()");
            ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

            while (rs.next()) {
                String guildId = Config.getGuildId();
                User user = jda.getGuildById(guildId).getOwner().getUser();
                String server = jda.getGuildById(guildId).getName();
                user.openPrivateChannel().queue((channel) -> channel.sendMessage("Your Verifus activation for your server `" + server + "` has expired. \nVisit https://verif.us/ to purchase.").queue());
            }
            connection.close();
            Sql.deleteExpiredGuilds();

            Connection connection1 = DataSource.getConnection();
            connection1.setCatalog(Config.getGuildId());
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement1 = connection1.prepareStatement("select * from `verifiedusers` where `expireDate` <= NOW()");
            ResultSet rs1 = preparedStatement1.executeQuery();
            while (rs1.next()) {
                User user = jda.getUserById(rs1.getString("discordId"));
                String serverName = jda.getGuildById(Config.getGuildId()).getName();
                Guild guild = jda.getGuildById(Config.getGuildId());
                String role = rs1.getString("roleId");
                user.openPrivateChannel().queue((channel) -> channel.sendMessage("Your role `" + jda.getRoleById(role).getName() + "` in the server `" + serverName + "` has expired.").queue());
                guild.getController().removeSingleRoleFromMember(guild.getMemberById(rs1.getString("discordId")), jda.getRoleById(role)).queue();
            }
            connection1.close();
            Sql.deleteExpiredUsers();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And here's part of the Main class that starts the service:

```
        PeriodicCheck periodicCheck = new PeriodicCheck(api);
        ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        try {
            scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(periodicCheck, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If I wasn't mistaken while making these, then I'm pretty sure that somewhere else in my program is causing this, and that will be hard to find.
Note that this did happen before when I was using `TimerTask` instead of `ScheduledExecutorService`, and it was because I wasn't closing my SQL connections, but I made sure to close all of them in my code.

If nothing comes up, I can provide more classes of my program, although I wouldn't know which one is causing it because it's happening randomly with each command. Could it be because of my computer/internet? I'm running this at home with my personal PC for testing.

There are also two other methods in my checker class that are not explicitly stated, here they are:
`Sql.deleteExpiredGuilds`:

```
        try {
            Connection connection = DataSource.getConnection();
            connection.setCatalog("verifus");
            connection.prepareStatement("delete from activatedservers where expireDate <= NOW()").executeUpdate();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

`Sql.deleteExpiredUsers`:

```
        try {
            Connection connection = DataSource.getConnection();
            connection.setCatalog(Config.getGuildId());
            connection.prepareStatement("delete from verifiedusers where expireDate <= NOW()").executeUpdate();
            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }
```

Comment: It is possible you are having an uncaught exception from scheduleAtFixedRate

Throws:
    RejectedExecutionException - if the task cannot be scheduled for execution
    NullPointerException - if command is null
    IllegalArgumentException - if period less than or equal to zero

Comment: ScheduleExecutorServices have the unfortunate policy of silently halting, if a task throws an exception, without providing any notification of that exception.  This is one of the few cases where `catch (Exception e)` (which you’re already doing) is warranted, in my opinion.  You might even want to change it to `catch (Throwable t)`, just to be sure some Error isn’t halting the executor.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try that when I can. Is there any better way of checking other than using `ScheduledExecutorService`?

Comment: You can change the default uncaught exception handler by using [Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler-java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler-)